# Exclude certain columns of a data set in a 'for' loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I currently am trying to perform a calculation on some of the columns in my data frame, this is a list of all the columns in my data frame.

```
>>> list(df)
['Time', 'England Apples', 'England Oranges', 'England Pears', 'England Apricots', 'England Watermelons', 'COAL', 'England Price', 'revenue', 'roll_rev_sum', 'roll_qty_sum']
```

However, in my *for* loop I don't want to select the `time` variable so I do this:

```
for col in df.columns[1:-1]:
```

This works well, however now I also don't want to include `England Price` in my calculation, in other words, I don't want it to be one of the `cols` in my *for* loop.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop a column (or even more) by its name:

```
for col in df.columns[1:-1].drop(['England Price']):
   print(col)
```

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of the columns you want, you can do

```
new_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['Time', 'England Price']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the previous answers have something missing. Use:

```
for cols in df.drop(['Times', 'England Price'], axis=1):
    print(cols)
```

This will do.